# make typescript to allow destructuring of undefined

Tags: typescript

I was migrating my code from JS to TS.

Now, My component takes array of objects, each dependent on the key

```
interface a {
 name?: string 
 lastName?: string 
}

interface b {
 email?: string 
 phone?: number 
}


const options:a | b = {email: 'itzrahulpatel@outlook.com'}

const {
 email, 
 phone, 
 name, 
 lastName 
} = options
```

Typescript here throws an error saying (say on email) something like this

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'b'
Property 'lastName' does not exist on type 'b'
```

Any idea how I can fix such errors? I have handled the undefined thing later in my code (this isn't actual code, just an example code).

Comment: More detail about `{...something}` snippet

Comment: @C-lioGarcia done

Comment: Can you please post your solution for someone who can facing the same issue?

Comment: `const options: a & b = {email: 'itzrahulpatel@outlook.com'}` does the trick

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [type union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields) here which means that `options` will have defined only the properties that are common for both `a` and `b`.

So for example if:

```js
interface a {
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
}

interface b {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const options: a | b;
```

Then `options` will have only `name` property defined.

In your case there is nothing in common between `a` and `b` so `options` is practically an "empty" interface;

What you need here is [type intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types).

If you define it as

```js
const options: a & b = {}
```

then `options` will have all of the properties from both interfaces.

Comment: I thought the same,  however ir is as if only properties of type `a` where allowed in the OPs example. It should not allow any property if the interface is empty, but properties of `a` are allowed in the destrucuturing. On the other hand, using the `const options: a & b = {}`, which makes perfect sense to me, I obtiain the error: `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.(2451)`.

Comment: Link to [TypescriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjsg3gWAFDJHAWwgH4AuZAZzClAHNkdkAbOKgOUJPKppHpwC+OHKEixEKAEYZGEAnGBMylanQa4ADgAsA9iC54ArgUnR1Q7DgR6qyHRrDAb5NADJk0gLwY5CpuQByYDAALyg4LUMmDThIJgABHUMwJh0dAGsAOmsCAIsrGzAZXF9FABp1ZG09CArGfCI63BZ2TmRzZG97RxscIA)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I encountered it too. change the property name to `name1` and poof the problem is gone, and everything works perfectly.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ maybe something in the way Typescript Playground is running...

Comment: Its not a matter related to this question. If you simply do `const name = 'John';` same error is obtained. Find the explanation [here](https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-name/) :)

Comment: Thank you for this clarification @rustyBucketBay!

Answer (score 0):

According this, my solution could be:

```
interface a {
        name?: string 
        lastName?: string 
    }
       
       interface b {
            email?: string 
            phone?: number 
       }

       const something:a | b = {
           name: "Célio",
           lastName: "Garcia",
           email: "cgarcia@celiogarcia.com",
           phone: 92100000
       }

       const options:a & b = {...something}

const {
 email, 
 phone, 
 name, 
 lastName 
} = options;
```

Hope it help someone who facing the issue.